# R: Smoothing Data (LargeDataset - A For Loop is Too Slow)

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, apply, smoothing

I'm aware there are many questions related to smoothing data in R, however, my knowledge is far too basic to apply it to the following problem! My key issue is that my data is >1.7m rows.

**My Problem**

I have a list "df" of 4 equal length vectors.

- df[[1]] is a vector containing **all uk postcodes**
- df[[2]] is a vector of latitudes
- df[[3]] is a vector of longitudes
- df[[4]] contains concentrations of a certain material

What I need to do is create a vector of 'smoothed' concentrations for each postcode, which should be calculated as: **"A weighted average of concentrations in all postcodes within a given distance. The weighting is defined as exp(-Distance)"**

I currently have the following code. It works perfectly (I've tested on a subset of 100k postcodes). However, it's far too slow, given the fact it loops over almost 2 million entries.

Can anyone help me finding a faster way to do this?

```
df <- as.list(Import[,c("Postcode", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Concentration")])

n <- length(df[[1]])
Out <- rep(0,n)

for(i in 1:n){
  #Calculate squared Euclidean Distance
  BaseLat <- df[[2]][i]
  BaseLong <- df[[3]][i] 
  Distance <- (df[[2]]-BaseLat)^2 + (df[[3]]-BaseLong)^2

  #Weightings
  Weight <- ifelse(Distance < 0.01, exp(-Distance), 0)

  #Take average rate and assign to output vector
  Out[i] <- sum(df[[4]]*Weight)/sum(Weight)
}
```

Comment: can you post a reproducible data .

Comment: Thanks for responding. If you look at http://www.doogal.co.uk/UKPostcodes.php you can download a full UK Postcode file. Just take the postcode, lat and long from that file and assign some random integers between 1 and 10 for the concentration column and you basically have my dataset. Does this work for you? I'm not sure how else to provide the data

Comment: It seems to me that the algorithm is of complexity O(n²). A little cosmetic: `Out[i] <- weighted.mean(df[[4]], w=Weight)`

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure that will help things along the way. I just can't help but think there must be a way which avoids the large loop. Then again, the distance calculation step makes me doubt this...